# If it is possible to animate image pixelation without canvas, using only CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image, pixelate

So you can get pixelation in CSS by doing the following:

- Set `background-image` to a very small image (say 50px or 100px).
- Set `image-rendering: pixelated` on the element.

That will give you the pixelated look.

Now I would like to animate this, by replacing the "very small image" with a large image after it finishes downloading by the browser:

```
let img = new Image()
img.src = largeVersion
img.onload = function(){
  // set css background-image to the new image perhaps, not sure...      
}
```

The problem is two-fold.

1. I want to have the `background-image` using `background-size: cover` so it properly fills the container element. So you can't use background-size in any pixelation animation.
2. `transform: scale(0.1)` (to get close to the original pixelation size) doesn't work because it scales the whole element.

I would like to do something like this: animate `transform: scale(x)` to go from 50px pixelated image to 2000px unpixelated image, over 0.3 or 0.5 seconds. But that doesn't work. I thought maybe using background-size, but that doesn't work either because of the constraint.

Wondering if there is any way to accomplish this.

I have seen [this](https://github.com/miguelmota/pixelate) which does pixelation using canvas. Wondering if there is no other solution that works without using JS/canvas.

```html
<style>
  div {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
  }
</style>
<div style='background-image: url(/100px.jpg)'></div>
```

Comment: a little confused, are you trying to animate from 1 background-image (50px pixelated image) to a new background-image (2000px unpixelated image) of the same element? Or are these 2 different DOM elements? Can you add the HTML?

Comment: I am trying to take 1 HTML element and swap out it's background-image with the big image. Then I was thinking of starting the big image off scaled small, so you could animate the scaling, and the pixelation would take care of itself. But I'm not sure that works.

Comment: something similar to this maybe? https://jsfiddle.net/hbw7pnet/1/

Comment: No, I don't want to scale (or animate the scaling of) the actual image like in that jsfiddle. I was using the image scaling idea to scale the bitmap so you draw a 50px image but then scale it to 2000px to get pixelation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do pixelation with an svg filter.
You can then animate the filter.
to use the filter on a div background you just do filter: `url(#filterid)`

put together it looks like this:

```css
#myDiv::before{
content:"";
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
filter:url(#pixelate);
background-size:cover;
background-image:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1475724017904-b712052c192a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2850&q=80)

}

#myDiv {
  position:relative;
  width:350px;
  height:250px;
}

.inside {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"> <div class="inside"><h1>Hello</h1></div> </div>
<svg>
  <filter id="pixelate" x="0" y="0">
    <feFlood x="4" y="4" height="1" width="1" />
    <feComposite id="composite1" width="10" height="10" />
    <feTile result="a" />
    <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="a" operator="in" />
    <feMorphology id="morphology" operator="dilate" radius="5" />
  </filter>

  <animate xlink:href="#composite1" id="anim-width" 
    attributeName="width" from="40" to="10" dur=".8s"
    fill="freeze" />  
  <animate xlink:href="#composite1" id="anim-height" 
    attributeName="height" from="40" to="10" dur=".8s"
    fill="freeze" />
  <animate xlink:href="#morphology" id="anim-radius" 
    attributeName="radius" from="20" to="5" dur=".8s"
    fill="freeze"/>
</svg>
```

Notice I had to create a inner div and apply the background on a pseudo-element `::before` but "soon" this will become unnecessary, when the support of `backdrop-filter` improves.

references:

Pixelate svg effect: https://codesandbox.io/s/km3opvn6yv

Animate an svg filter: https://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/dPRVqL

backdrop-filter: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter

Comment: Excelent answer!